# Laravel 5.2.x disable specific middleware

Tags: php, laravel, testing, laravel-5, middleware

Is it possible to disable a specific middleware without disabling all middleware?

I will use it when running tests, so I don't want to define middleware groups and then assign them to my routes.

```
$this->withoutMiddleware(); // <-- This will prevent all middleware 

$this->withoutMiddleware('web'); // <-- What I want is something like this
```

Answer (score 5):

I have an alternative solution, you could add a condition in your impacted middleware according to your environnement :

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if (App::environment('testing')) {
        return $next($request);
    }

    // Your middleware logic

    return $next($request);
}
```

Comment: I think this should be a good solution for me. I wish there was a method that you can disable a concrete middleware.

Comment: I don't know the existence of such a function. It could be a smart pull request for the laravel repo

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can use [middleware groups](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/middleware#middleware-groups) which is a much better approach. Define a few groups, and assign them to your routes.

Comment: Web, mentioned in the question is (likely) a middleware group already. Even so, this doesn't explain how to disable a single middleware, or middleware group.

Answer (score 0):

You may add particular routes to the $except array in the middleware itself.

For example: I didn't want my api routes to have web middleware, so this is what i did in VerifyCsrfToken.php

```
protected $except = [
    "api/*",
    "more/routes",
];
```