# Laravel testing without specific midleware

Tags: laravel, phpunit

I've write a middleware to build a menu, but when I run my tests It tooks about an hour (It's a huge menu)
I want to know if there's a way to disable this specific middleware for testing but not using:

`use withoutMiddleware;`

because this also disable the auth middeware and my tests depends on it.

Thank you.

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/q/36747390/1293040

Comment: How diasable Specific middleware http://stackoverflow.com/a/36588855/1293040

Comment: You can mock that middleware handle method in every test and return the specific response.